# Display inherited Attributes in Xcode data model editor?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

Does any smart Xcode pro out there know if it is possible to tell Xcode to display an Entity's inherited Attributes and Relations in the data model Editor when looking at a specific Entity? It seems cumbersome when learning or creating large data models to have to click the parent to see what is defined there.

To perhaps help clarify with a contrived example:

I have a "Base" Entity with Attributes "dateCreated", "dateDeleted".
I then define a "Person" Entity inheriting from the "Base" Entity and add Attributes "firstName" and "lastName".

When I click on the Person Entity, I'd like Xcode to show me ALL attributes inherited+defined for the Person Entity: "dateCreated", "dateDeleted"+"firstName" and "lastName".

Thank you Stackoverflow community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode unfortunately does not support this. File an enhancement request at http://bugreport.apple.com/ and maybe one day they'll add it. Then add your bug report at http://www.openradar.me and I'll post a duplicate.